# Workflow Foundation: How to create Receive activity with custom message in xaml designer?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I need to have Receive activity which can receive my custom data. I found examples, but all use coded workflows like such

```
public class ProcessRequest : Activity
 {
     public ProcessRequest()
  {
      Variable<MyData> request = new Variable<MyData> { Name = "request" };

   Receive receiveRequest = new Receive
   {
       ServiceContractName = "IProcessRequest",
    OperationName = "Foo",
    CanCreateInstance = true,
    Content = ReceiveContent.Create(new OutArgument<MyData>(request))
   };
  }
 }
```

The main point is that `Receive.Content` property. It is not clear for me how I can do it in XAML designer. What I have to set in the dialog of the `Content` property - Message or Parameters and what to set inside those options?

Thanks for the light!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it :-) I have to use *Message* option inside the *Content* dialog. Then put the name of the variable (in my case `request`) into the field *Message data* and browse `MyData` type for the *Message type* field. Piece of cake ;-)